# How to horizontally center a form-inline element inside a <td>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[DEMO JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/0ae7own9/1/)

How can I center horizontally all the contents? Especially the contents of the second `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `margin:auto` to row tag to `<div class="row" style="margin:auto">` as follows:
https://jsfiddle.net/01rewj56/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed mt-5">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Reference Genome</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;">Annovar version</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center;"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" name="referenceGenomeSelect">
                            <option value="1">hg19</option>
                            <option value="2">hg38</option>
                        </select>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <div class="row" style="margin:auto"> <!-- added margin auto --> 
                                <div class="col">
                                  <input type="text" id="annovarVersion" class="form-control" placeholder="Please select a file...">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="document.getElementById('annovarVersionInput').click()">Browse</button>
                                  <input type='file' id="annovarVersionInput" style="display:none" onchange='updateInputText(this.value, -1)'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" >Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Cheknow

why you used the table the  Bootstrap version 4

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/
Inline
Group checkboxes or radios on the same horizontal row by adding .form-check-inline to any .form-check.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">3 (disabled)</label>
</div>
```